# Excel VB Macro to search for static text then move over 2 cells and input data

Tags: excel, vba

I'm a noob so please bear with me.
I have a workbook, Column B contains a list of ID's of the format "V000001...V000999", 1 per row these do not change and remain static.
There may be anywhere from 100-1000 rows in the sheet with each of the V #'s being unique.

Each unique V# has one of 4 outcomes that I need to put into column D.
I created a Macro using the Macro recorder that searched for V000001, then moved over 2 cells and entered "NA", no big deal.

V000002 (or next in line sequentially) may not need any answer or it may need an "NF".

Here is the simple code the macro recorder made to do this:

```
Cells.Find(what:="V0007921", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
    MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "NA"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Range("A1").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Site Responsibility"
ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Range("A1").Select
```

What ends up happening is that I have that block above 100+ times in my macro, with the V# changing each time, this is not efficient and it also caused the macro size to exceed the max allowable.

I know which V#'s should receive an "NA" in Column D and I also know which V#'s should receive a "NF" in Column D.
Is there a way to call a text file or define the NA and NF list of V#'s in the VBCode and have the macro parse it efficiently?

I hope that makes sense above, appreciate any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the search/update in a Sub and call it for each value. Better still you could drive it from a list on a sheet.

Eg:

```
UpdateValues "V0007921", "NA", "Site Responsibility"
```

Sub:

```
sub UpdateValues(ID,status,notes)
    dim f as range
    Set f = Activesheet.columns(2).Find(what:=ID, LookIn:=xlValues, _
                                         LookAt:=xlPart) 'xlWhole?

    if not f is nothing then 
        f.Offset(0, 4).value = status
        f.Offset(0, 2).value = notes
    end if

end sub
```

Comment: Thank you Tim, I'll give that a try this week.

I'm not sure though about the first line above of 
    UpdateValues "V0007921", "NA", "Site Responsibility"

where does that go?  Are you suggesting that I create a line in the macro like that for each V#?